# How to fix crash force closes in Android React Native AssembleRelease

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I made the application react natively when the DEBUG mode went smoothly but when it was released, when the application entered it crashed immediately

I have gradle clean, delete node_module, follow the medium tutorial and look for answers in StackOverflow

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I expect a solution for this, even though when BUILD Success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check logs. Connect your device via USB and run in terminal

```
adb logcat *:E
```

Following article could be useful as well https://medium.com/@impaachu/react-native-android-release-build-crash-on-device-14f2c9eacf18.

UPDATE:
I've checked your apk with

```
adb logcat *:D
```

And found out following

```
08-20 12:31:04.487 21145 21214 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
08-20 12:31:04.487 21145 21214 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
08-20 12:31:04.490 21145 21214 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
08-20 12:31:04.511   779   800 I ActivityManager: Displayed halo.jasa.startup/.MainActivity: +325ms (total +1s114ms)
08-20 12:31:04.546 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.551 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.555 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.555 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.558 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.559 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.562 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
08-20 12:31:04.568 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.575 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
08-20 12:31:04.579 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
08-20 12:31:04.583 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
08-20 12:31:04.584 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.587  1911  2095 W SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.
08-20 12:31:04.587  1911  2095 W SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.
08-20 12:31:04.590 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.591  1911  2095 I StreamController: cleanUpControllerScope(nowcards-15-2463d-9a60)
08-20 12:31:04.591 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.593 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.595 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.596  1911  2095 W SearchServiceCore: Abort, client detached.
08-20 12:31:04.601 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
08-20 12:31:04.604 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.605 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
08-20 12:31:04.609 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.610 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
08-20 12:31:04.613  1911 21220 I PBSessionCacheImpl: Deleted sessionId[8406233173500478] from persistence.
08-20 12:31:04.616 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.623 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
08-20 12:31:04.626 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.627 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.629 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.629 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.632 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
08-20 12:31:04.637 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
08-20 12:31:04.639 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.640 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
08-20 12:31:04.641 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.642 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
08-20 12:31:04.652 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.657 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.662 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.663 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.668 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
08-20 12:31:04.671 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.671 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextShadowNode
08-20 12:31:04.672 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.henninghall.date_picker.DatePickerManager
08-20 12:31:04.675 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninButtonViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.676 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapCalloutManager
08-20 12:31:04.678 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapMarkerManager
08-20 12:31:04.690 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapPolylineManager
08-20 12:31:04.694 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapPolygonManager
08-20 12:31:04.698 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapCircleManager
08-20 12:31:04.701 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapManager
08-20 12:31:04.711 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapLiteManager
08-20 12:31:04.712 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapUrlTileManager
08-20 12:31:04.715 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapLocalTileManager
08-20 12:31:04.718 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapOverlayManager
08-20 12:31:04.720 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientManager
08-20 12:31:04.724 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.725 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.727 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLikeViewManager
08-20 12:31:04.730 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager
08-20 12:31:04.733 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSendButtonManager
08-20 12:31:04.733 21145 21214 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method boolean com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButtonBase.canShare() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.TextView
08-20 12:31:04.735 21145 21214 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBShareButtonManager
08-20 12:31:04.738 21145 21214 D SoLoader: About to load: libyoga.so
08-20 12:31:04.738 21145 21214 D SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/data/halo.jasa.startup/lib-main
08-20 12:31:04.738 21145 21214 D SoLoader: libyoga.so found on /data/app/halo.jasa.startup-1/lib/arm
08-20 12:31:04.738 21145 21214 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libyoga.so
08-20 12:31:04.739 21145 21214 D SoLoader: Loaded: libyoga.so
08-20 12:31:04.750 21145 21214 D SoLoader: init exiting
08-20 12:31:05.103 21145 21213 W ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
08-20 12:31:07.060 21145 21213 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "halojasa_com" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime: Process: halo.jasa.startup, PID: 21145
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStorageModule$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncStorageModule.java:65)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStorageModule$1.doInBackgroundGuarded(AsyncStorageModule.java:143)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStorageModule$1.doInBackgroundGuarded(AsyncStorageModule.java:130)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedAsyncTask.doInBackground(GuardedAsyncTask.java:32)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedAsyncTask.doInBackground(GuardedAsyncTask.java:20)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-20 12:31:07.218 21145 21190 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 4 more
08-20 12:31:07.219   779  1065 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity halo.jasa.startup/.MainActivity
```

I see it could be related to the maps library
try to update you google play services to the latest versions

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base: 17.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

Comment: Yes I have done that, and there is no error log, there is only a warning "MainActivyti.exit"

Comment: And probably can you share your apk file?

Comment: 08-20 16:13:51.307  2983  3050 E WindowManager: win=Window{d126a29 u0 halo.jasa.startup/halo.jasa.startup.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8, caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:748 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:732 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5646 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:553 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_DisplayContent_21578:476

Comment: @zidniryi can you share your apk, so I can check on my end?

Comment: @dimitri this my apk file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QTd_qn-52_4_DSoJ8YXaSTSNMDTWTNTb

Comment: @dimitri you got something in my apk was send. Thanks

Comment: Now iget error like this @dimitri : > Task :app:processReleaseManifest FAILED
/Users/halojasa/mobile/latest/halo-express-v2-feature-review/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).